# How do I set default time in timedropper.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to set a custom value for the input type using `timedropper.js`?

I am using `timedropper.js` but it gives me a default time or value i.e. `03:48 am`. I want to set to a custom value like `0:00`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the documentation. I found the information you need on [a site](http://felicegattuso.com/projects/timedropper/).

If you click on the "option" link, you will see some options. One of them is what you need: `setCurrentTime`. The description of it is:

> Automatically set current time by default.(Default: true)
>   If set "false", the input "value" attribute is considered as main time value.

[image: screenshot website]

That explains why the current time is being displayed when you are using the timedropper plugin. If you want to prevent that, you have to set that option as `false`.

So, just have the following HTML. Note the `value` attribute where I have set it as `00:00`. (or pick another time if you want)

```
<input type="text" id="alarm" value="00:00" />
```

then activate timedropper with

```
$( "#alarm" ).timeDropper({setCurrentTime: false});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it by setting value to input. It works only when option **setCurrentTime**  is set to **false** (default true).

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="alarm" value="10:30 AM" />
```

and js:

```
$( "#alarm" ).timeDropper({ setCurrentTime: false });
```